# Android GET request: How do I send to a webpage (OAuth2.0)

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth-2.0

I'm currently trying to implement the MyAnimeList API to an android app, and I'm slowly understanding what I'm supposed to do thanks to this info:
https://myanimelist.net/blog.php?eid=835707
However, I'm stuck on how to implement some of this in Android Studio. I have the Authenication URL created, but how would I send the app into a webpage, and get the "https" address after clicking allow?
My code currently has a button that executes this code:

```
try {
    //This recieves a pkce verifyer and challenge from PkceUtil.kt
    val pkce = PkceUtil()
    val codeVerifier = pkce.generateCodeVerifier()
    Log.d("PKCE Log", "Code verifier = $codeVerifier")

    val codeChallenge = pkce.generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier)
    Log.d("PKCE Log", "Code challenge = $codeChallenge")

    //MyAnimeList GET request
    val clientId = MyAnimeListAPIClientId().getClientId()
    //Note: state is recommended, idk what it does
    val authString = "https://myanimelist.net/v1/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=$clientId&code_challenge=$codeChallenge&state=RequestID42"
    Log.d("AuthURLTest", "$authString")
    var receivedString: String
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        authString,
        { response ->
            Log.d("TEST", "$response")
            receivedString = response
        },
        { error ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: $error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    )
    queue.add(stringRequest)

} catch (ex: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
    Log.d("PKCE ERROR", "UnsupportedEncodingException")
} catch (ex: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    Log.d("PKCE ERROR", "NoSuchAlgorithmException")
}
```